# How can I get SOESupport to handle Polymorphism?

Tags: arcgis-server, c#, json

I've got some business objects below that I can serialize and deserialize successfully with [Json.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/).  I don't see a simple way to do this with [Esri's SOESupport](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Working_with_JSON_in_a_REST_server_object_extension/000100000nw6000000/) however.  I'm happy with Json.NET, but I'd like to leverage Esri's IGeometry conversion routines.  Is there some way to get SOESupport to work for this?

**Update:**

Since it doesn't look like Esri can do this, I'm trying to use Json.NET. See my related issue on stackoverflow:

[How can I deserialize with TypeNameHandling.Objects in Json.NET Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860565/how-can-i-deserialize-with-typenamehandling-objects-in-json-net-silverlight)

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Dog: Animal 
{
    public bool LikesBones { get; set; }
}
public class Cat: Animal 
{
    public bool LikesMice { get; set; }
}
public class Zoo
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    private List<Animal> m_Animals = new List<Animal>();
    public List<Animal> Animals { get { return m_Animals; } set { m_Animals = value; } }
}
```

Is there some way to get Esri's JsonObject to support this sort of test?

```
public static void Test1()
{
    // use Json.NET
    Zoo z1 = new Zoo() { ID = 1 };
    z1.Animals.Add(new Dog() { Name = "Fido", LikesBones = true });
    z1.Animals.Add(new Cat() { Name = "Felix", LikesMice = false });
    string s1 = Util.Serialize(z1);                

    Debug.Print(s1);
    var z2 = Util.Deserialize<Zoo>(s1);
    string s2 = Util.Serialize(z2);
    Debug.Print(s2);
    if (s1 != s2)
        Debug.Print("failed");
    else
        Debug.Print("ok");
}
```

I can apply settings in Json.NET that force the typename to be serialized, allowing [polymorphism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173152%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for the list of Animals.  How can I implement these same functions with SOESupport?

```
public static string Serialize(object o)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, Formatting.Indented, settings);
}
public static T Deserialize<T>(string s)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    settings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(s,settings);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short version is "I don't think so". You might be able to extend ESRI's conversion classes, but frankly, it'd be a whole lot easier to make custom Json type converters with Json.NET, and attribute your geometry fields as needed.

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(ESRIGeomConverter))]
    public IGeometry location { get; set; }
}

public class ESRIGeomConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override CanConvert( Type objectType )
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override Object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        // use ESRI conversion to get an IGeometry from the reader:
        // Conversion.ToGeometry(jsonPoint, esriGeometryType.esriGeometryPoint)
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializer serializer )
    {
        // use ESRI conversion to get Json for the IGeometry in "value"
        // SOESupport.Conversion.ToJsonObject((IGeometry)value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Herb.  Since I'm using the same class library within both the silverlight app and the SOE, I can't have any dependencies on arcobjects.  Instead, I'll put the conversion routines in a separate assembly.   I hope people developing javascript clients will be able to consume my service using [methods described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/185429/how-to-use-json-to-create-object-that-inherits-from-object-type).  If not, it seems like I might as well use SOAP.